# Socat - is it possible?

Tags: linux, port-forwarding, socket, socat

Is there any way to listen and execute a command ( for every connection ) while port forwarding with socat? A non-working example to make it more clear:

socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,reuseaddr, "exec:ls" fork tcp:localhost:80

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
socat tcp-listen:8080,reuseaddr,fork system:'ls; exec socat - tcp\:localhost\:80'
```

- 1st parameter gets `,fork` to have `socat` stay listening for more connections
- `system:` is preferred over `exec:` to have a shell interpreter and easily run an additional command after the `ls` command,
- which is a new `socat` command

  which will have stdin/stdout connected to the remote client's output/input and will forward it bidirectionally again to the next destination. Note that its `:` separator (and a few other special characters) must be escaped with a `\` to not confuse the *first* `socat` command. If this line becomes more complex it become easier to simply exec a script like this:

  ```
  socat tcp-listen:8080,reuseaddr,fork exec:/path/to/myscript.sh
  ```

  with `/path/to/myscript.sh`:

  ```sh
  #!/bin/sh
  ls
  exec socat - tcp:localhost:80
  ```

  `exec` in the shell command is optional but avoids uselessly leaving around the shell.

`socat` also exports a few variables of its own that can be reused in the script, that you could check for example like this (with a connection made):

```
$ env - socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,reuseaddr,fork exec:printenv
SOCAT_PID=1057351
SOCAT_PPID=1057284
SOCAT_VERSION=1.7.4.1
SOCAT_SOCKADDR=127.0.0.1
SOCAT_SOCKPORT=8080
SOCAT_PEERADDR=127.0.0.1
SOCAT_PEERPORT=42970
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks!(: Just one more tip please: using that line, how would you decode strings in base64? I mean: the data passing through port 8080 are base64 encoded, but I want to decode it before the data reach port 80 ( the data coming back from port 80 must not be encoded )

Comment: As soon as you use a pipe somewhere (eg: `base64 -d | socat ... `), communication won't be completely bidirectional. Then this probably requires forking some commands in the script to get two half directions working . You should expose (probably in a different question) your full problem. Check https://xyproblem.info/ . You think you can solve it with Y = socat, but we don't know anything about X. Even if socat can solve it, I can't tell because I don't know your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help!! I will come up with a new question and I will notify you if you want!(;

Comment: actually for this specific case it's easy, except you get a problem with timing: no way to know when input ends so the communication has to end first and  there probably won't be a reply sent back in time then. here's the line to put in myscript.sh : `exec base64 -d | socat - tcp:localhost:80`. `-` means STDIO, and while input comes from `base64 -d` output is sent back unaffected, as written in the comment.

Comment: I posted the relative question if you are interested in (: https://serverfault.com/questions/1070792/bidirectional-communication-unidirectional-decode

Comment: You just rewrote an XY problem, while I already gave the answer in comments. My comment told it was working bidirectionally in the end. Sorry if that's not what I wrote in the former comment.

Comment: I got the perfect solution, check the question if you want!(: